# Masonry Image Organization from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, masonry

My goal is to call an API, which returns JSON data. On successfully retrieving the data, I would like to put the retrieved image into a gallery, organized with the Masonry library. This should work for initially loading data, and endless scrolling to load more data when the user scrolls down the page.

The code below works well for grabbing and organizing the first set of data. It loads nine images and uses Masonry to organize them. But, when I scroll down the page to load more images, all of the current images get pushed down the page. When I scroll down again the same thing happens. So I end up with a bunch of white space at the top of the page.

I was attempting to roughly follow the example that I found here;

http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/iHevA

Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
function loadThumbnailImages(thumbDate) {

// Format the date into YYYY-mm-dd format for the API
formattedDate = this.formatDate(thumbDate);

$.jsonp({
// The URL to parse the JSON from
url: 'dataURLGoesHere' + formattedDate, // any JSON endpoint
// if URL above supports CORS (optional)
corsSupport: false,
// if URL above supports JSONP (optional)
jsonpSupport: false,

// If the JSON from the URL was successfully parsed
success: function(data){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    if(data.media_type == "image")
    {        
      var item = '<div class="masonry-item"><a href="#" class="thumbnail" align="middle" style="max-height: 350px; max-width: 350px;"><img src=' + data.url + ' class="thumbImage img-responsive"/></a></div>';
      items += item;

      if(doneLoading)
      {

        var $container = $('#masonry-list').masonry({
          itemSelector: '.masonry-item',
          columnWidth: 50
        })

        $container.append(items);

        $container.imagesLoaded().progress( function ( imgLoad, image) {
          var $item = $(image.img).parents('.masonry-item');
          $container.masonry('appended', $item);
        });

        items = "";
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out. Adding the two lines $container.masonry('reloadItems') and $container.masonry('layout') manages to load the images and responsively place them in the correct place. Hopefully this can help someone in the future!

```
        var $container = $('#masonry-list').masonry({
          itemSelector: '.masonry-item',
          columnWidth: 50
        })

        $container.append(items);

        $container.imagesLoaded().progress( function ( imgLoad, image) {
          var $item = $(image.img).parents('.masonry-item');
          $container.masonry('appended', $item);
          $container.masonry('reloadItems'); //<--- This line and 
          $container.masonry('layout'); //<-------- This line fixed the problem
        });
```